# Updating specific things in an XML file

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to create a tool that updates content in an XML file.
My biggest issue is how do I get the program to know where to update what.

Here is an example of the first five lines of XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<monster name="Demon" nameDescription="a demon" race="fire" experience="6000" speed="280" manacost="0">
    <health now="8200" max="8200"/>
    <look type="35" corpse="5995"/>
    <targetchange interval="5000" chance="10"/>
```

Let's say I want to modify the value of experience, how do I go about that?
I've looked around this website for already existing instructions, but none relate to something like this.

I am using C# Windows Form.

Comment: If you're familiar with LINQ I would recommend using LINQ-to-XML. If you're not familiar with LINQ, well then get familiar with LINQ!

Comment: If your _intent_ is to read/load from the XML the "monster" data and build an equivalent object, play around with that "monster" in your application, then to later write/save that object back, perhaps you should consider using the [XmlSerializer](http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/csharp/xmlserializer-example.htm) and simple POCO objects to represent the data.

Comment: That data looks like something you'd load in it's entirety to use it - why not just load it all into whatever class you use, change what you need and save it all back? Would be easier than changing just parts of it. Unless you're making some generic tool, of course. (edit: looks like i was just ninja'd by another chris)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Linq to Xml you can:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml); // load xml file
// query for data you want to update
var experience = xdoc.Root.Attribute("experience");
experience.SetValue(42); // update data
xdoc.Save(path_to_xml); // save updated data
```

Comment: I suppose I could start learning to use Linq, anyone have a solid guide I could use?

Comment: @user1880591 you can start from [LINQ To XML Tutorials with Examples](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=564) also I suggest you to get LINQPad for learning LINQ

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous ways you could do this:

1. Using [XMLDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) and other built-in classes in .Net.  You could open the file and load the XML into the class and then use [XPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx) to get to the attribute.  This would be similar to @lazyberezovsky's answer.
2. The hack-y solution would be to do the string parsing of the text of the file.  Look for the `experience="` and note that from that and the next `"` is the value you want to change.  This wouldn't be my first suggestion but I have done this at times when I wanted the quickest hack to change an XML file.